# "Like ... also"

Tags: grammaticality, construction, redundancy

*First off, I would like to apologise if this has been asked before - I did do a search on here, but there were far too many results to go through!*

Take for example this sentence:

> **Like** you, I **also** have to [do sth.]

I don't think it's an uncommon *verbal* construction, but, grammatically, is it acceptable?

**Questions:**

1) Is the "also" superfluous; does it have the same function as "like" in the above example?

2) If it is superfluous, does it necessarily mean the sentence is grammatically incorrect? And does its acceptability differ in speech as compared to writing?

Comment: That sentence could easily mean "We both have to do this as well as [our normal work]"; are you asking about the construction or your implicit limitation to those contexts where both words have the same referent?

Answer (score 1):

A redundant  thinking / writing is not necessarily grammatically wrong
but in this case "also"  changes the sense of the sentence to whom is talking. He or she becomes the center, and leaves "you" behind.